# Checking on the progress of a stored procedure by using another stored procedure

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, multithreading, stored-procedures

I am currently working on a project that is utilizing a python script to read a text file and push that data to a stored procedure in a mySQL database. But the way that I have written it I am unable to read the resulting data from the stored procedure because it is happening in a different thread than my main thread. I tried seeing if I could just create another stored procedure on my main thread and see how many lines have been inserted so far, but because its has to be on a different connection I'm not able to see what the first stored procedure is doing. Is there a way to create a single mySQL connection that my entire script can see on multiple threads or is there a setting I need to change in mySQL. Also I plan on doing a lot more threading with this in the future so if I need to create a new connection for each thread how can I dynamically create connections. Keep in my I'm also trying to keep the code as simple as possible for the next poor SOB who has to take my place once I leave. This is pretty much what I have so far but this gives me a 'double free detected in tcache 2' error.

Stored Procedures

```
sp_1 (IN iname VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO table (names)
   VALUES (iname);
END

sp_2 (OUT ocount INT(11))
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(names) INTO ocount
   FROM table;
END
```

Python code

```
import mysql.connector
import time
import threading

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(<connection string>)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

def Main()
   data = []
   data = <large array of names>
   curcount = 0
   
   #upload the list to the database
   DatabaseConnection('sp_1', data, 'Multiple')

   #see how its going
   while curcount < len(data) :
      time.sleep(1)
      curcount = int(DatabaseConnection('sp_2', 0, 'Single'))
      print(curcount)
   mycursor.close()

def DatabaseConnection(spName, spData, spMode)
   result = ''
   if spMode == 'Single' :
      result = mycursor.callproc(spName, spDatq)
   if spMode == 'Multiple' :
      t0 = threading.Thread(target=MultiDatabaseConnection, args=(spName,spData,))
      t0.start()
   return result

def MultiDatabaseConnection(spName, spData)
   for i in spData :
      mycursor.callproc(spName, i)
```

Comment: is this question about `mysql` or abour `sql server` ?  They are both very different database servers

Comment: I have removed the tag [tag:sql-server], due the OP stating they are using a "mySQL database" and the use of a library called `mysql.connector`. Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using when asking questions.

Comment: I apologize, I got a little click happy with the tags.